# Floats without width go to the next line on long content

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble when using floats. I have a container that has an image and content. They are arranged side by side. The size of the image is always **fixed** based on device while the content size should adapt to the rest of the container, so I don't want to use width for the content.

When I don't add width, the content drops to the next line because it tries to fit content to 100% of the container instead of extending vertically. Here is the preview of what happens: http://codepen.io/gasim/pen/zxRRYb. And here is the code. HTML:

```
<div class="news-item clearfix">
  <div class="image-container"></div>
  <div class="main-container">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.news-item {
  width: 900px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 350px;
}

.news-item .image-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  background: red;
}

.news-item .main-container {
  padding: 10px;
}

.news-item .image-container, .news-item .main-container {
  float: left;
}
```

How can I make it extend the width of `.main-container` to the end of `news-item` automatically? I don't want to use JS or Flexbox model for that.

Answer (score 0):

Set display property of  .image-container and .main-container as "inline-block" .
Then set width of the .main-container according to your choice in % .

Comment: inline-block is painful to use because I don't know the width.

Comment: Firstly if you are using a div you don't have to assign a display:block property to it.(A div is already block). Secondly , In my opinion for placing two divs adjacently easiest way is to set their display : inline-block .

Comment: yes but if you don't know the width of the second block, it doesn't work. The second block's width needs to be `100% - WIDTH_OF_FIRST_BLOCK`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a while I found out that, removing `float: left` from the `main-container` fixes the issue. I think the reason is same as using text and wrapping it around an image. But since the box cannot be wrapped around, it works as expected.